# Making elemental phosphorus from phosphoric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

What is the most efficient way for making pure or semi-pure elemental phosphorus, by using phosphoric acid as an source of phosphorus?

Comment: You'd need to _reduce_ it to elemental phosphorus. I'm afraid you didn't bother to check even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus). Also this is quite broad, it's not like there's only one method.

Comment: @Mithoron I searched for about 6 pages before wikipedia. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a well-equipped chemical lab at your disposal, or is it more like a home/kitchen experiment? Or is it rather a theoretical question?

Comment: @andselisk home/kitchen experiment just for curiosity.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this because this is not a safe and efficient method, but in theory one can mix sand and charcoal powder/grains, then soak the mixture with phosphoric acid in a can, and then heat it up in an oven. If  you are lucky, you can obtain white phosphorous powder on a bottom. Remember that white phosphorous and its vapors are highly toxic!

Comment: @andselisk Much appreciated, thanks, i'll do it outside and with a mask, it should have no problems using some metalurgy tools that i have here.

Comment: @andselisk I don't believe this can work at all. Reduction of phosphates with carbon requires heating well above 1000°C. Phosphoric acid will evaporate way before that.

Comment: http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=13932 and https://www.google.com/patents/WO2010029570A1?cl=en

Comment: @IvanNeretin That's why it was a proposition, not an answer. Sure some H3PO4 will escape, but some will still react. Ideally you want to convert phosphoric acid to Ca3(PO4)2 by adding chalk/lime, but that will require even higher temperatures of approx. 1600°C to reduce phosphate with charcoal.